# Are questions about the job of being a legal professional off topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

## Background

The topics in scope for this stack exchange tend to reflect creations of the law, procedures, and interactions with lawyers as outlined [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-should-be-on-topic-for-law-se?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> - Statutes or court decisions
> - Legal terms and language  doctrines and theory
> - Legal process and procedure
> - Historical legal applications
> - Dealing with legal professionals

And the one notable off-topic reason is [*specific legal advice*](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/add-close-reason-to-handle-questions-that-should-be-asked-of-lawyers).

There doesn't seem to be an indication about whether questions realting to the profession of a lawyer itself is within scope. This is something that I am curious about, and those who would want to become lawyers would also be curious about.
This is distinct from this [dealing with lawyers](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-questions-asking-about-dealing-with-lawyers-but-not-about-the-law-itself) question in that I am talking about the profession of a lawyer itself, but similar in that it deals with an unmentioned area of scope.

## Example

The question I was planning to ask (which I did not ask yet, since I was not sure of scope) was based off [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/how-much-patience-is-needed-in-a-phd/108968#108968) from the Academia SE about patience needed in a PhD.  My idea for it goes as follows:

> In addition to the work required for schooling, what additional grit
>   must the common lawyer be prepared for on the job?

The purpose of this question would help give perspective to those on this stack exchange that might have an interest of being a lawyer.  It's not unreasonable to assume that those interested in the law on this sight might intersect with the group of people who are interested in becoming a lawyer.

## Question

Are questions about being the profession of a lawyer on or off topic?

Comment: Could you provide an example, so that we are all talking about the same thing?

Comment: @TimLymington added the example I was thinking of asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. Okay, so I'm in two minds about this.

On the one hand, yes, I suppose practising the law is probably something that a lawyer might do. And yes, as a prospective future lawyer, you might be interested in it.

However, I can't help but feel as though this will end up being very very opinion-based, and that answers that are given will necessarily reflect personal experience. I suppose some things that are mandated by law might be consistent from person to person (though perhaps even only within a jurisdiction - e.g. *What professional registrations are required to practice law?*).

Even now, most questions can have multiple answers based on jurisdiction; asking about the profession of being a lawyer, outside of the rules and regulations surrounding it, might result in many divergent answers.

Comment: Therefore...if I am understanding you correctly, the parameters of my question must be pretty well defined when it comes to being a lawyer.

Comment: I think so. Things like... *What is the most important thing for a lawyer to do?* is probably not great. However, something like *What is the professional association for practicing lawyers in New South Wales, Australia?* can be answered. Does that help at all?